# Paginate large amount of data

Tags: mysql, performance, count, pagination

Something is very common results of a search, for example, paging, and is usually shown the total page, results, etc ...

Two examples:

Google - https://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=h4PzVLy3JMiU8QeE3ICYBQ&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=test - approximately 2.67 billion results (0.39 seconds)

Stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=test - 1,561,211 results

For example, Google, assumes that these 2.67 billion results are found by the database to be counted. As is done to count the total results of a query with many results without compromising performance? What magic is this?

Comment: Is your question about pagination or about the count? This is not so clear to me. One thing to remember: Google is *not* using a SQL database for queries, so it is difficult to talk about Google here. Google's engine is better compared to a Non-SQL or In-Memory database (but has its own design).

Comment: For full text searches normally are used special full text search engines, which are implemented besides the normal SQL engine (even when some SQL databases bring an integrated full text index (this is implement above the normal engine)).

Comment: I Got You. There is definitely not how to do this in MySQL? We will need something like **ElasticSearch**? As is done in pursuit of **stackoverflow**? It is with elastisearch too?

Comment: ElasticSearch is one tool to do full text searches, yes! Google of course has its own high-performance implementation. The capabilities of this implementation is one reason for Googles advantage.

Answer (score 0):

"approximately 2.67 billion results (0.39 seconds)" -- Notice the word "approximately".  That opens the door wide open to tricks that allow it to do the count in virtually 0.00 seconds.  Examples:

- Do some counts every night
- Statistically sample
- Have summary tables

"1,561,211 results", on the other hand 'sounds' like an exact count.  But it may be a "stale" result.  I refreshed that page a few times; the value did not change.  This leads me to believe that they really count it, but then cache the result for some time.  Memcached is a likely suspect for such caching.

(There are doubtless other tricks of the trade.)

Comment: If it were only one table, it would be easy to tell, even using EXPLAIN could but become a problem using joins or filtering by any column in the table, then it is impossible. What I wonder is this "no one ever need to use a grid with a giant table?". We develop a system for two years and only now with larger tables and joins'm going through this problem. In your opinion, does not exist as definitely solve this problem? Thank you.